# checkedTextView OnClickListener .setChecked() not working

Tags: android

I have created a Custom Adapter and applied it to listView,  but when I click a CheckTextView item the **.setChecked()** method won't change the state of the radio button on the UI.

```
int getPosition = position;
checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                Log.i("Username", Title.get(getPosition) + " is no longer checked");

                checkedTextView.setChecked(false);

            } else {
                Log.i("Username", Title.get(getPosition) + " is checked");
                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);


            }

    }
});
```

However the logs are showing that the view is being checked and unchecked.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Changed the layout and put a `CheckBox` beside the text instead and it works perfectly fine. Is there a bug with CheckTextView?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why its happening but i have an idea to implement it in another way

Assuming your are using custom adapter to load list items

set OnClickListener for CheckedTextView at the time of view creation in your custom adapter

```
final CheckedTextView ct = (CheckedTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
ct.setText("text");
ct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // do what ever you want to perform here
    if(ct.isChecked()){

     } else {

     }
 }
});
```

Comment: Changed the layout of your app and put a CheckBox beside the text instead and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah I'm using that now but unsure why CheckedTextView doesn't work as expected. Thanks anyway